# Replace linebreaks inside a macro

Tags: latex, tex

When I write a macro for an invoice to not retype the clients name and address it looks like this

```
\def\client     {FirstName LastName\\ Streename. 12\\ 12312 Berlin}
```

it works great in most cases but there are situations I want the `\\` be replaced by a `$cdot$` or something similar or even a comma.

Does anyone know how to get there?

Comment: Don't use `\\ ` for line breaks (with the exception of tables)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an helper macro which can be redefined according to where it shall be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}{\par}
\def\client{FirstName LastName \foo{} Streename. 12 \foo{} 12312 Berlin}

\begin{document}

\client 

\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\foo}{$\cdot$}
  \client
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could split the information into multiple macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\GivenName{FirstName}
\def\Surname{LastName}
\def\street{Streename. 12}
\def\city{12312 Berlin}

\begin{document}

\GivenName{} \Surname

\street

\city

\GivenName\space$\cdot$\space\Surname\space$\cdot$\space\street\space$\cdot$\space\city

\end{document}
```